# Booleans SQL and PHP validation

Tags: php, sql, admin

I have a column in  a table (users) called admin and its datatype is boolean. Two users are set to "true"

My objective is when those two log in, they have acess to the back office, but so far the code isn't working:

```
   <?php

    session_start();

    $error="";
    $successMessage="";



    if ($_POST){
    if(!isset($_POST["salada"]) || $_POST["salada"]===""){
    $error = "PHP: An email is required <br>";
    }



    if(!isset($_POST["arroz"]) || $_POST["arroz"]===""){
    $error .= "PHP: A password is required";
    }

    if ($error !=""){
    $error = '<div class="error-login">'.$error.'</div>';


    }else {

    require("MGconfig.php");


    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["salada"]);
    $pwd = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["arroz"]));


    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "select name, id from users where     email = '".$email."' and password = '".$pwd."'");


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !==1){
        $error='<div class="error-login">PHP: Invalid email or   password</div>';
        header("Location:index.php?error=".$error);

    }else {

            $nome = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

            $_SESSION["name"] = $nome[0];
            $_SESSION["id"]=$nome[1];



            header ("Location: main.php");
        }
      }


    }

   ?>

 <?php

  if($_SESSION['admin'] !=0){

        header ("Location:admin.php");       
    }?>
```

Can someone tell me why isnt working? Is Syntax? If I compara the field "name", the restriction works...Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends on how you set that session. Show that code, it's relevant to the question.

Comment: Try to `echo $_SESSION['admin'];` to test for its value. Could it be that somewhere else in your code it gets assigned a string value?

Comment: i dont think so, the value has been assigned in the DB directly...

Comment: and if i write, for example  if($_SESSION['name'] =="some name"){

        the restriction works fine...

Comment: Is admin also some name?

Comment: no, admin is just the name of the column users...i dont get it...

Comment: Please be more specific. Which part of the code is *not working*?

Comment: the last php part: as it is, the program ignores the if statement and goes to the back office, wathever the user is...

Comment: but as i said earlier, if i compare the field name: if($_SESSION["name"]=="Bob"...the back office is only available to the bob user...

Comment: @icenine What's the datatype of *admin* column?

Comment: it's tinyint(4), but i guess it's the same as boleean right?

Comment: @icenine `BOOLEAN` and `TINYINT(1)` are same. Also, I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you haven't selected `admin` column in the `SELECT` query, you have only selected `id` and `name` columns. Plus, there's nowhere you're checking whether the logged in user is admin or not.

So the solution is, select the `admin` column in your `SELECT` query and make use of that column value to check whether the logged in user is admin or not, like this:

```
// your code

$result = mysqli_query($connection, "select name, id, admin from users where email = '".$email."' and password = '".$pwd."'");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 1){
    $error='<div class="error-login">PHP: Invalid email or   password</div>';
    header("Location:index.php?error=".$error);
}else{
    $nome = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $_SESSION["name"] = $nome[0];
    $_SESSION["id"] = $nome[1];
    if($nome[2]){
        // logged in user is admin
        $_SESSION["admin"] = true;
    }else{
        // logged in user is not admin
        $_SESSION["admin"] = false;
    }
    header ("Location: main.php");
    exit();
}

// your code
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection. Also see [how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for the help Rajdeep and everyone else